# How to hook up 15 amp RV to power a space heater or small dehumidifier

Tags: electrical

I am a trailer newbie. Please forgive my ignorance. I am purchasing a small travel trailer with 15 amp power base.

What do I need to purchase in order to power a space heater and/or small dehumidifier?

What adapter is appropriate to connect to 30 amp shore power at RV park/campground?

The more I've researched, the more uncertain I've become.

Thank you.

Comment: If the trailer is set up for 120 volt AC power, then should just need to plug in a space heater.  Most space heaters will use most of the 15 amps, so can maybe only use a light with it.  If the trailer is set up for DC(battery) power, then need devices that work with DC power.  Most RV stores should be able to help.

Comment: It would really help if you gave us the manufacturer, model, and year of the trailer that you have purchased.

Comment: The RV connection should have a normal outlet (sometimes 2) as well as the 30, or 30 and 50. If they don't, you'll need a portable power distribution box (plug in sub-panel) to safely connect to a 30A outlet. The most convenient place to carry that is built into your trailer, at which point it would not be a "15 amp" trailer...

Comment: If you only have a 15 amp setup you should be fine at any park. Code (nec 551.71) requires every site with an electrical supply to have 1 20 amp 125 volt receptacle (today these are almost exclusively GFCI protected). I have a 125v 30a adapter to 20amp that I purchased at camper world most RV stores sell them so they are available but they are usually flexible, I just have not seen the model @jonathan J shows below but these are commonplace at locations that cater to small RV’s we called them dog bones and had them that went from 30 to 15/20 and 15 that went to 30 to plug in at a tent site.

Comment: Are you sure that a standard 15 or 20 amp receptacle is not available at the campground?  My experience has been that they generally include 3 receptacles - 50 A, 30 A, and an ordinary 15 or 20 A.

Answer (score -2):

#### Disclaimer:

**This is an easy way to start a fire and destroy your RV and everything in it.**

"They" make an adapter that allows you to plug in a NEMA 5-15P plug into a NEMA TT-30R receptacle. But read on below the picture...

[image: Travel Trailer Power Adapter]

However, such an adapter is technically a code violation, because it allows you to connect a cord rated for 15 amps or less to a circuit protected by a 30 amp circuit breaker.

If you do go this route (which I can't advise because it's so easy to overload things and cause a fire), use a 10 or 12 AWG cord between the campground pedestal and your travel trailer, make sure the cord is a short as possible (to reduce voltage drop), do not coil the cord (coiling prevents heat dissipation and could cause a fire), and use a heater rated for 750 watts or less. Do not cover the cord with anything.

Monitor the cord and all connections when the heater is in use. If there is any sign of overheating, discontinue use of the heater immediately.

Comment: I'm not really sure I can support a 1-line answer with 4 paragraphs of warnings about code violations and "don't do this". You do realize that many people stop reading when they've seen what they want and that the picture is a big visual break that may make the rest of the text mentally "disappear".

Comment: I'm not sure it's a code violation.  The UL White Book authorizes such gadgets if it has an internal fuse at an appropriate value (15A here).

Comment: *use a heater rated for 750 watts or less* Ha ha ha! Nearly all inexpensive heaters for sale in the US are ~ 1400 watts, because that's what you can put on a 15A circuit.

Comment: Love how people criticize this answer but don't offer one of their own.